# How do I demonstrate that I've read relevant research in a motivation letter

Tags: publications, application, research-undergraduate, internship, application-cover-letter

I am an undergraduate applying for a research internship at another university. The application guidelines for the position specify that the motivation letter must show that the applicant has read a few papers on the research topic. How do I include this information in the letter? Should I mention specific papers or just express what I've learned from reading some of the research on the topic?

The field is Computer Science, in case that makes a difference.